# How do you change the return key text in Mobile Safari keyboard without the form tag?

Tags: keyboard, virtual, mobile-safari, return, enter

I would like to change the the "return" button text on the **Mobile Safari** keyboard when my input element is focused. I know you can do this:

```
<form action="somewebsite.com">
  <input id='SearchTextBox' type="search"/>
  <input id='SearchButton' type="button" value="Search" />  
</form>
```

But I don't want the form tag because the search is ajaxian (I don't want to reload the page).

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heh, should have thought of this (coworker solved). Just cancel the form submission with JavaScript. For example:

```
<form action="#" onsubmit="return false;">
  <input id='SearchTextBox' type="search"/>
  <input id='SearchButton' type="button" value="Search" />  
</form>
```

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to do the same thing, but I don't get how this sets the return key's text.  If I want the iOS keyboard to have a "foo" submit key, where would "foo" go in your code?

Comment: @TahoeWolverine <input id='FooButton' type="button" value="foo" />

Comment: It looks like this works when you have a <form> element wrapping your input and when the input has value="Search".  If you have another value, the keyboard's return key is "Go".

Answer (score 4):

You can now use `enterkeyhint`

```
<input enterkeyhint="search" />
```

Theres more options like "send", "go", etc